# Notify my computer when mobile phone rings

Tags: notifications, mobile-phone

I'm looking for a software that can be installed on my computer and notifies me when my cell phone rings. I often listen to loud music with headphones and cannot hear when someone calls me.

*Update*

It's an ordinary Nokia phone.

*Update 2*

I'm interested in a solution for OS X or (Fedora) GNU/Linux.

Comment: What kind of phone?

Comment: Which operating system?

Answer (score 1):

If it's an Android phone you can use Android Notifier. More info here:

http://www.softsailor.com/news/41803-download-android-notifier-to-receive-alert-notifications-from-phone-to-computer.html

Comment: The link in the question doesn't appear to be valid. Try this one instead: https://code.google.com/p/android-notifier/

Answer (score 1):

The [Nokia PC Suite](http://www.nokiausa.com/get-support-and-software/software/nokia-pc-suites/how-to/calls-and-messages) including Nokia Communication Centre should be able to satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Voice. If somebody calls your Google Voice number, it can ring your cell phone and notify you via a ringing sound from the gmail web site from which you can also answer your call from.

Comment: Yes, it *would* be great, but "Google Voice is not available in your country". It's US only.

Answer (score 0):

There are rather a lot of variables - but something involving bluetooth would probably work (assuming both the phone and the computer are suitably equipped).

If you can set the PC to be a hands-free device for your phone then you'd hear the ringing through the headphones. Of course this also throws up problems the other way round (not hearing your phone ring because its routed through the PC and hence the headphones) but its a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I use Google Voice, and when I receive a call my laptop's speakers instantly make an incoming ring noise.  It overrides any current audio even when playing games, so I never miss a call.  I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

This is built-in functionality of iOS for Apple computers. Not sure if it's possible for iPhone on Windows computer...

Now that I'm at my computer, you can have your Apple computer ring when your iPhone rings by adding your phone number to your Apple ID and in FaceTime preferences (on your computer), checking the box labeled "Calls from iPhone."

Comment: Since the question is about OS X (macOS) and/or GNU/Linux, this answer is not really relevant. Please make it at least marginally useful by describing *how* to do this. … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Yet another example of an SO comment that a) is wrong and b) is a case of "I'm here to police, not to actually help."

It *is* relevant because Apple computers use macOS (OS X), so when I say that this is built-in functionality of iOS (that would be the OS used on the iPhone, produced by Apple, Inc, in Cupertino, CA, USA) and Apple computers (which uses OS X or macOS), I don't see how you could not see it as being relevant.

When I posted the information, I didn't have my computer in front of me, so sorry I couldn't give a complete answer On. The. Spot.

Comment: I'm sure that the OP has been sitting idle for TEN YEARS waiting for my full and complete answer with graphs, screenshots and complete step-by-step instructions.

Take a step back and remember that this site here to HELP people, not shame them, or bully them or show people *trying* to help how they failed.

Sometimes an amalgam of answers can reach the desired solution, whereas any one single answer fails to.